# Laravel Eloquent orderBy() parent table field in a One to Many Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

So I have the table `questions` and the table `steps`. The `steps` can have many `questions`. The `question` belongs to a "step".

I have a `step_id` field in my `questions` table, which is a foreign key of the `id` field in my `steps` table. I also have a `number` field in my `steps` table that does NOT have anything to do with the `id` field. It's just a number (1-12).

Questions Table

```
---------------------------
| id | step_id | question |
---------------------------
```

Steps Table

```
-----------------------------
| id | number | description |
-----------------------------
```

I have the relationship working fine as I can create, update, and delete questions from the `questions` table. However, I'm working on the index page, and I want to grab all the questions and sort them by the `number` field in the `steps` table.

Ive done a little bit of research and I've found this little bit of code from Laracasts, but it's not working. Not much information was given on the site. Do I need a dependency to get this functionality, or is there a native way to do this in laravel.

```
$questions = Question::join('steps', 'questions.step_id', '=', 'questions.id')
->orderBy('questions.number', 'asc')
->get(['questions.*']);
```

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'questions.number' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `questions`.* from
>   `questions` inner join `steps` on `questions`.`step_id` =
>   `questions`.`id` order by `questions`.`number` asc)

Maybe I just don't understand relationships well enough to do this. But i'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break down what's wrong with this query (also note that you're doing a normal SQL join here, not using the Eloquent relationship - which is correct for this case):

```
// You are comparing the `step_id` on `questions` to the `id` on `questions`
// Which doesn't make sense, you should compare it to the `id` on `steps` table
$questions = Question::join('steps', 'questions.step_id', '=', 'questions.id')
    // You're trying to order by a column on `steps` table, but
    // you're explicitily looking for it on `questions` table
    ->orderBy('questions.number', 'asc') // <-- you get the SQL error because of this
    ->get(['questions.*']);
```

Now let's fix those issues:

```
$questions = Question::join('steps', 'questions.step_id', '=', 'steps.id')
    ->orderBy('steps.number', 'asc') 
    ->get(['questions.*']);
```

Comment: Good answer. Good explanation.

Comment: +devk @devk Thanks for the answer, now is there a way to paginate this result? I forgot to ask that in my previous question.

Comment: @J.Robinson Yup, just do this: `->select('questions.*')->paginate()` instead of `->get(..)`.

Comment: You sir are an ABSOULUTE BOSS! thank you SOOOOO much! :P This helps a ton! :P Got it to work 100% they way i wanted!